# What are file formats that store skeletal movements, and are there databases of them?

Tags: 3d, animation, skeletal-animation

I have a set of 3d vectors representing the positions of a character's hand, foot, shoulders and so on. Is there any kind of easy to read file I can use to animate those with walking, standing, jumping etc motions? Is there a database with some of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most 3D animation/modelling programs support [BVH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume_hierarchy) file format for motion captured skeletal animations. There is free BVH database at https://sites.google.com/a/cgspeed.com/cgspeed/motion-capture/cmu-bvh-conversion and you can quickly test the downloaded animation at http://www.akjava.com/demo/bvhplayer/